# Handling strings (path to files) with wildcard in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PS script that looks for specific files in different directory.

My code looks like this

```
# $Path is provided by the user, it's a path like
# $Path = "C:\Some Directory\Project [ABC]\Files\"
# There's a check to ensure path ends with a backslash

$PDFFiles = Get-Item $($Path + "*.pdf")

for ($counter=0; $counter -lt $PDFFiles.Length; $counter++) {
    # Do stuff
}
```

The issue is that $Path may have character considered as wildcard (eg `[` or `]` in my example), but I can't use `-LitteralPath` because I need the `*.pdf` wildcard to be interpreted.

- **How to properly handle strings to tell PShell that this part is litteral, and this one is a wildcard?**

Answer (score 3):

Use `Get-ChildItem` instead of `Get-Item`.

Pass the path of the folder to `-LiteralPath` and then use the `-Filter` parameter for the wildcard file name filter:

```
$PDFFiles = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Filter "*.pdf"
```

`-LiteralPath` will not attempt to expand wildcard sequences in the path

---

An alternative approach is to escape the `$Path` value:

```
$escapedPath = [WildcardPattern]::Escape($Path)
Get-Item -Path (Join-Path $escapedPath *.pdf)
```